# how to print the sum of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to print the sum on each list in the dictionary but the error comes back as TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, not sure what to do.

```
def pass_bags(s,j):

  plane={}
  plane['Spirit']=s
  plane['JetBlue']=j
  return plane
def show_bags(bags, airline):
  for i in range(len(bags)):
      for x in bags[airline][i]:
          print (type (x))
s=[[5,6,7,7,8],[9,3,5]]
j=[[2,8,9,7],[2,3,5,6]]
```

what it needs to say is

```
On Spirit Airlines:
person 1 has 5 bags weighing 87 lbs
person 2 has 3 bags weighing 17 lbs
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Where are you calling the functions you have defined?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is not working? It worked on my console without changes. I just saw sum(x) in your error print. I guess you are trying to use sum function on original code that you did not posted here. And that is why you  are getting error. Coz sum will try to iterate over the object given and you have 'int' there not a 'list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to index the dictionary to iterate only over the lists associated with that key. For each key, sum each sub list and print details.

```
def show_bags(bags, airline):
    for i, l in enumerate(bags[airline], 1):
        print('person {} has {} bags weighing {} lbs'.format(i, len(l), sum(l))
```